# sort -u cannot remove the duplicate lines

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to the Linux shell commands, and I am learning `sort` command.

The input file is as follow:

```
a 1  
b 2  
a 0
```

I want to make the first column as key for sort and use '-u' option to remove the line "a 0", because it has the same key with the first line and the command manual says '-u' will keep only the first of an equal run.

When I used the command `sort -k 1 -u text`, the result is:

```
a 0  
a 1  
b 0
```

And however, when I used the command `sort -k 1, 1 -u text`, the output is:

```
a 1  
b 2
```

Can anyone tell me what the difference between the two commands is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-k 1
```

will sort from field 1 till the end of line.

```
-k 1,1
```

will sort only by first field. You defined stop position.

That is the reason why you got different output.

Read `KEYDEF` in sort man page.

Answer (score 2):

`-k` option is setting the key as fields from position [to position]. So `-k1` is not descriptive (actually useless) since it defines the whole record which is the default.  By setting `-k1,1` you're asking sort to use only the first field as the key, hence the desired result.